# Amount does not exceed the estimate of 0 to 9

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

How to make amount does not exceed the estimate of 0 to 9

example

```
A1:A2 = A3 

if A3 is 10   ... HOW TO MAKE IT TO RETURN 0 
if A3 is 11 return to 1 
if A3 is 12 return to 2 
if A3 is 13 return to 3 
if A3 is 18 return to 8
```

Answer (score 1):

USE MOD, as in the following VBA code

```
11 MOD 10 = 1
18 MOD 10 = 8
10 MOD 10 = 0
```

As pointed out by Brad, the worksheet version is

```
=MOD(A1,10)
```

Comment: This is written as `=MOD(A1,10)` in Excel